# Rails before validation throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to implement a pivate message system in rails, and this is my table:

```
create_table :messages do |t|
  t.integer    :sender_id,          :null => false
  t.integer    :recipient_id,       :null => false
  t.text       :content
  t.boolean    :read,               :null => false, :default => false

  t.timestamps
end
```

and this is my `message` model:

```
  attr_accessible :recipient_id, :sender_id, :content

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :recipient_id, :sender_id, :content

  before_validation :recipient

  def recipient
    self.recipient_id = User.find_by_email(self.recipient_id.to_s).id
  end
```

and my form:

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => {:action => 'index'}, :as => :message do |message| %>
  <%= message.text_field :recipient_id, :placeholder => "to" %>

  <%= message.text_area :content, :placeholder => "i am saying..."%>

  <%= message.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

and controller:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  @message.sender_id = current_user

  if @message.save
      set_flash "Message sent"
      render 'index'
  else
      set_flash "Message Failed"
      render 'index'
  end
```

end

The idea is that *user 1* enters *user2* email inside the `recipient_id` text field then the before validaion will fire and retrive the *user 2* id based on his email from the `user table` but when i try it i get this error:

```
undefined method `to_i' for #<User:0x00000004344780>
```

What is the problem?

**Edit:**

this is the line throwing the error:

```
@message.sender_id = current_user
```

if i change `current_user` to `current_user.id` it thorws this error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

on this line:

```
    self.recipient_id = User.find_by_email(self.recipient_id.to_s).id
```

Thanks

Comment: You stacktrace should point to the file and line of code where the error is initiated. Please add this information.

Comment: @iltempo - Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the create method,

```
@message.sender_id = current_user.id
```

instead of this `@message.sender_id = current_user`.

I think you are setting `sender_id` with the `current_user` object when it is expecting an `id` integer.

**EDIT:**

For the new error, the `User.find_by_email` method can't find a record, so it's returning `nil`.

There is also a problem with your code,

```
self.recipient_id = User.find_by_email(self.recipient_id.to_s).id
```

You are setting `self.recipient_id` and searching with `self.recipient_id`. `self.recipient_id` seems to be `nil` unless `self.recipient_id` is set somewhere else.

If there was a recipient in the database that matched the `self.recipient_id`, this code wouldn't be doing anything. It would be setting `self.recipient_id` to `self.recipient_id`.

Comment: Now i am getting this error `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`